# React Native - how to change color on one element?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-stylesheet

I'm trying to make a small quiz app in react native.
At the moment I'm trying to figure out how to change the color on the button that I press. Right now the color changes on all of my buttons, which is not correct, since I want to show green if the answer is correct and red if the answer is incorrect.

The problem is that I'm using hooks and it feels like most of the previous questions/answers on this topic is using classes and I'm kinda bad at understanding that.

I ran into a great solution be someone here in stackoverflow (don't remember the name) who posted this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/87zn91ga/1/. Unfortunately this was not made with a hook and I've been trying to read and understand how I can convert it.

This is my code for my buttons/boxes/text or whatever I should call it and this is where I want the color change to take place. There are some code here that I might not use (sorry if its a bit messy).

```
<View
        style={tailwind(
          'flex-1 items-start justify-start flex-row flex-wrap h-64 mx-5',
        )}>
        {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption, i) => (
          <View
            key={i}
            style={tailwind(
              'w-40 h-32 m-1 border-2 border-white bg-blue-400',
            )}>
            {/* <Button title={item.text} onPress={() => console.log(item.id)} /> */}

            <Text
              // style={tailwind('h-32 text-white text-2xl')}
              style={{
                // backgroundColor: color,
                // color: textColor,

                color: clicked ? 'yellow' : 'red',
                height: '100%',
              }}
              onPress={(index) => {
                handleAnswerOptionClick(answerOption.isCorrect);
                setCount(1);
                // setFavorite(true);
                setClicked(i);
                handleClick(i);
              }}>
              {answerOption.answerText}
            </Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
```

So what I would like to get help with is to make a hook that will change the color of the box/button pressed to green or red depending if the answer is correct or not. I'm pretty sure I can figure out how to make the statement for showing the correct color.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the next function:

```
const [color, setColor] = useState("")
const changeColor = () => {
    clicked ? setColor("yellow") : setColor("red")
}
```

And in style you put it like:

```
style={{color: {color} }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use React Native 0.63.x, you can use a [`<Pressable/>`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) component

```js
import { Pressable } from 'react-native';

<Pressable
  onPress={(index) => {
    handleAnswerOptionClick(answerOption.isCorrect);
    setCount(1);
    // setFavorite(true);
    setClicked(i);
    handleClick(i);
  }}
>
  {({ pressed }) => (
    <Text
      style={[tailwind('h-32 text-white text-2xl'), { color: pressed ? 'yellow' : 'red' }]}
    >
      {answerOption.answerText}
    </Text>
  )}
</Pressable>;
```